# How to customize a single default taxonomy page?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

In Drupal, we have default taxonomy pages. These pages have the same view. We want to change the layout of one of those pages. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to change the layout of one specific taxonomy term page or all taxonomy term pages?

Comment: I want to change to the layout of texonomy tag pages.but it's design and view are same as other texonomies.so when i try to change one texonony then other are automatically changed...    what the solution????

Comment: If you are using Views, you can add a *Filter* for the **Vocabulary**.

Comment: yes it's view.but how can i change default texonomy layout.it changed other texonomy pages also.i don't want to change other one..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard issue taxonomy module to output your pages, eg:

```
www.yourhost.com/taxonomy/term/###  (or whatever its eventual alias is)
```

you can modify `taxonomy-term.tpl.php` to do almost anything you want.

In D7, it's provided for you and basically looks like this:

```
<div id="taxonomy-term-<?php print $term->tid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>">

  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php print $term_url; ?>"><?php print $term_name; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content">
    <?php print render($content); ?>
  </div>

</div>
```

The key variable to your question is `$term` and you could do something like this:

```
<div id="taxonomy-term-<?php print $term->tid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>">

  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php print $term_url; ?>"><?php print $term_name; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content">
    <?php if ($term->tid==THE_TID_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR): ?>
       <?php // do something different here ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <?php print render($content); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 7:**

1. You need to have a separate view for that particular taxonomy term.
2. Create a views page
3. Under contextual filters, select Taxonomy term id > Provide default value > Fixed value > Enter the taxonomy term ID here.
4. content which is displayed on this views page will be only for a particular term ID.

In case if you have to do the same for other terms, then just add a new page within the same view and set the taxonomy term ID and the page URL should be different.

**Drupal6:**

Create a node view

1. Create a node view and page display
2. Add a filter for a specific content type
3. Add the fields as you require
4. Under 'Arguments' add 'Taxonomy Term ID'
5. Select 'Provide default argument' > 'Fixed entry'
6. Mention the term ID under 'Default argument'
7. Now when you run the page link, you'll see nodes related to a specific term

Comment: can you tell me this for drupal 6.28......

Comment: Updated the above answer